# Command .startservice() not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell, service

I have a little script where the user enters the script name (the description name) and has the option to modify the properties. This is done with a GUI interface: a textbox and some drop-down lists.
I tried several ways to make it but none of them worked.

Here is how I retrieve the service information:

```
$thisservice = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $Server | Where {     $_.displayName -eq $serviceBox.text }
```

I look at `$server` computer and match up the "service display name" to the value contained in the textbox field: `$_.displayName -eq $serviceBox.text`. This works well, if I list the data I get exactly what is in the service console: .name, .description, .state, .startmode, .displayname

I store the service name in a variable:

```
$servicename = $thisservice.name
```

I know you can not start a service unless it is on "Manual" or "auto" so first I set it to auto. Here I tryed to different ways but none worked:

```
$servicename.ChangeStartMode("Auto")
```

and

```
 Set-Service $servicename -StartupType Auto
```

and then I start the service (but this doesn't work either even if I preset the state-mode on Auto form the service manager):

```
$servicename.startservice()
```

Also the `$servicename.stopservcie()` fails.

I tried this on 2 different machines, on both I have admin rights, I tryed running the script with Admin mode, same result. I even tried it directly from PS console and I couldn't change the service state!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here: `$servicename = $thisservice.name`

By doing that you set `$servicename` to be a string, not the service object. Therefore you can't call service methods on it any more.

You should be able to just do:

```
$thisservice.ChangeStartMode("Automatic")
$thisservice.StartService()
```

Comment: Ok... i didn't knew that. Thank you! I just tried your version and I've got the same result. My test is the "Fax" service on my laptop. currently it is in "Stopped" and "Manual" . After I run the script it is the same. Can it be something from the system that actually doesn't allow me to change the state?

Comment: Make sure the changestartmode is `Automatic` not `Auto`. Changing start mode works on my machine but the service won't start even through services console because it immediately stops due to it not being in use. So maybe check it will actually start via Services.

Comment: I tried a different service. At least now the start works. The start-mode still remains in Manual. Is it possibla to catch that message that windows returns when the service is automatically stopped?

Comment: I doubt it, and because it actually starts you can't check the return code for an error either. The only way I can think is to check the status after starting, but it would take an arbitrary amount of time to enter "Running" state, so difficult to do in a complete fashion.